# Structuring User Entry in a Textbox by way of Uneditable Symbols

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, user-interface

I'm creating a windows form that requires (among other things) the user to provide latitude and longitude values, with precision down to thousandths of a second.

For aesthetic reasons, I'd like to have this all in one textbox. I imagine the best way to do this is to have certain constant symbols (namely, those for degrees, minutes and seconds) in a textbox to signal to the user the proper place for degrees, minutes and seconds. These symbols should not be editable by the user, and ideally would not change their orientation. That is, I imagine something like the following:

```
00°00′000″
```

Where each zero is an editable field.

Is there an easy way to do this through leveraging existing .NET controls (MaskedTextbox, say)? Or will this require some old-fashioned elbow grease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaskedTextbox is the easiest way to go.

To get what you are looking for, set the following properties:

```
mtxtText.Mask = "00" & Chr(176) & "00" & Chr(146) & "000" & Chr(148)
mtxtText.PromptChar = "0"
mtxtText.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals
mtxtText.CutCopyMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals
```

You can of course season to your needs.  BTW, Chr(176) is the degree symbol, Chr(146) is the closing single quote and Chr(148) is the closing double-quote.  You will have to parse your result in order to get the degrees, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Perfect. This was exactly the functionality I was looking for.